# Emulate sql Server ROW_COUNT() for SQL Server Version 8.00.760

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I need to make a query with the ROW_NUMBER() function in order to enumerate all purchase order Lines order by the PurchaseID and date of delivery:

```
SELECT
    PL.PURCHID,
    PL.LINENUMBER,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PL.PURCHID
                       ORDER BY PL.LineNumber, PL.DELIVERYDATE DESC) AS LineNumberOrdered
FROM AXDB13_R1.dbo.PURCHLINE PL
WHERE PL.DATAAREAID = 'pol';
```

the thing is that the database production is too old that does not recognize that function. How can I emulate that?

thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please include the current query.

Comment: Select PL.PURCHID, PL.LINENUMBER, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PL.PURCHID ORDER BY PL.LineNumber, PL.DELIVERYDATE DESC) as LineNumberOrdered
from AXDB13_R1.dbo.PURCHLINE PL
Where PL.DATAAREAID = 'pol'

Comment: I have attempted an answer below, please try it.

Comment: Post sample data the demonstrates your issue in a consumable format (i.e., not jammed into a comment). It would also help to know what the primary and unique keys are for this table.

Answer (score 0):

We can replace your call to `ROW_NUMBER` with a correlated count query, which generates counts over what previously was each partition of `PURCHID`:

```sql
SELECT
    PL.PURCHID,
    PL.LINENUMBER,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM AXDB13_R1.dbo.PURCHLINE PL2
     WHERE PL2.PURCHID = PL.PURCHID AND
           (PL2.LineNumber < PL.LineNumber OR
            PL2.LineNumber = PL.LineNumber AND
            PL2.DELIVERYDATE >= PL.DELIVERYDATE)) AS LineNumberOrdered
FROM AXDB13_R1.dbo.PURCHLINE PL
WHERE
    PL.DATAAREAID = 'pol';
```

Comment: PurchId ShippingDateConfirmed LineNumber LineNumberOrdered
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 3.0 2
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 4.0 4
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 4.0 4 <--I have tried but i repeats 
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 5.0 5
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 6.0 6
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 7.0 7
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 7.5 8
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 8.0 9
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 9.0 10
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 10.0 11
28858-1 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 11.0 12

Comment: That would seem not possible assuming you are actually comparing to the query in your question above.  Same table, same where clause, means same number of records.

Comment: The original salesorder has two different sales lines with the same LineNumber. also all delivery dates are the same. comes like that from the database. I havent changed anything :/. also is not always start from 1 (one)

Comment: Without having your actual data in front of me, this is as much help as I can give now.  See if you can take my answer as a starting point and make it work.